# Error while launching client file using Protractor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, protractor

I tried run a simple JavaScript code in eclipse using protractor. It was working well before but suddenly a error popped up stating..

> Error while launching client file
>   Client file cannot be empty.

Whereas, the protractor config file and working directory in the run configurations are well and good.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue with eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).
Tried with Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) and was able to configure protractor.

Comment: Same issue in Neon 4.6.0

Comment: same issue with Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2), could you please help me. out how to fix this.